# How do you interrupt an osquery query that's been running for too long?

Tags: osquery

I have run a sqlite (via osqueryi to be more precise) query on the command line, after several minutes the results keep on coming. `^C` isn't interrupting it. Are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

osquery uses the sqlite library, so this is not a sqlite question.

As for why `osquery` might ignore `^C`, that's sounds like the it's blocked on some underlying disk IO. As I understand it, if you're blocked on disk IO, unix processes can't exit.

But there's a lot of details missing to diagnose this.